# NSPredicate with keypath on the right side

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, core-data, nspredicate

I need to use a NSPredicate like this:

```
NSString *authorNameAndLastName = @"Name LastName";
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%@ beginswith[cd] %K",authorNameAndLastName,@"name"]
```

but it doesn't work and I receive this exception:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'unimplemented SQL generation for predicate ("Name LastName" BEGINSWITH[cd] name).'
```

After a lot of try I suppose I can't put a keypath (name) in right side of the predicate expression.
It's right?
There's a workaround to obtain what I need in this specific case?

Answer (score 0):

This only would work with arrays and sets. Core Data doesn't support this type of predicate.

Have you tried using [NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:]?

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(YourObject *object, NSDictionary *bindings) {

    NSComparisonResult result = [authorNameAndLastName object.name options:(NSCaseInsensitiveSearch|NSDiacriticInsensitiveSearch) range:NSMakeRange(0, [object.name length])];
    if (result == NSOrderedSame) {
        return YES;
    }

    return NO;
}];
```

Comment: I can't, because i use the predicate in a SQLite request.